# Object expected error in Internet explorer 8

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer

I am working in `IE8`, I want to call a javascript function in my php code. That code is written like:

```
<li onclick="selectservice(<?php echo $Service->id; ?>);"> Service </li>
```

and this js function is written as :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectservice(serviceid)
{

    var baseurl = "<?php print Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>";
    var url = "#";
    var data= 'serviceid='+ serviceid;

        $('#chs_service_act').hide();
        $('#serivesloading').show();
        $.ajax({
        dataType : 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        url : url,
        //cache: false,
        data : data,
        complete : function() { },
        success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#servicelist').hide();
                $('#stafflist').show();
                data=$(data).find('div#stafflistcontent');
                $('#stafflist').html(data);
            }
    });
    return true;

}
</script>
```

This is working fine in `Firefox`, `Chrome`, but when I am trying to run this into `IE 8`then I am getting error :

`Object Expected at line 388`

```
<li onclick="selectservice(<?php echo $Service->id; ?>);"> Service </li>
```

Comment: What does that line look like when you "View Source"?

Comment: You probably need single quotes around the service id, if it's not numeric `selectservice('<?php echo $Service->id; ?>');`

Comment: in view source it looks like `<li onclick="selectservice(42);">`

Comment: Show us generated HTML source from IE (F12)

Comment: @Nadh its a numeric value only

Comment: Remove argument, try to check if function execute, then add back and check again. Error could be in another place

Comment: Are you sure that is line 388? I can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @FSou1 the code is at http://trycodeonline.com/testing/6c0d4a6c7b5e75655c69f6252e1ed349

Comment: Make sure that IE is not throwing errors on page load.  It could be that it is not loading up the selectservice function due to an error in the script.

Comment: When I am trying to get the `typeOF` then it is returning `undefined`

Comment: @MattTew In view source it is loading the function selectservice

Comment: @lord_linus How can an `<li` be a clickable link? Haven't you tried using an `href` with a JS call to your function instead?

Comment: @Fred are you new to HTML, we can make anything clickable, its working fine in chrome and FF

Comment: @lord_linus Short answer: **"NO"**. **Are you new at using IE 8?**

Comment: Yep, thats why i am asking that question,

Comment: IE has a little bit of problem with JavaScript. It detects some values as an object like, weird behavior! Do yo have any jQuery or any kind of script file loaded before this function? If yes, try to put all of them at the end of the page, I mean out of `</html>` tag. One time this helped me!

Comment: Would it make any difference in IE if I put the function in body instead of head

Comment: @MahanGM sorry it didnt worked for me ...

Comment: @lord_linus My last solution is to checking developer console in IE. I can't remember if it has any developing tools at version 8 because I'm not using it anymore. Check to see whether there is an error or not.